# C/C++ library for reading MIDI signals from a USB MIDI device

Tags: c++, c, signal-processing, midi, dev-c++

I want to write C/C++ programs that take input from a MIDI device.

The MIDI device connects to my PC using a USB connector.

I'm looking for a (C/C++ implemented) library that I can use to read the MIDI signals from the MIDI device through the USB port.

I'm happy manipulating the MIDI data once I get it, I just don't want to have to implement the code for its capture.

I'm planning on writing my code using the Bloodshed Dev-C++ IDE on Windows XP.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[PortMidi](http://portmedia.sourceforge.net/portmidi/) is another open source cross-platform MIDI I/O library worth checking out.  On the other hand, if you are working on a sysex type of app, then direct Win32 works easily enough.

Just came across another open source cross-platform framework that includes MIDI support: [Juce](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce/).

Also, I should note that there isn't anything special about a USB connected MIDI device.  It will still be presented as a MIDI device in Windows and you will use standard MIDI APIs (mmsystem) to communicate with it.

[July 2014] I just came across [RtMidi](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/) that looks to be a nice, compact, open source cross-platform C++ library.

Comment: Just looked at PortMidi, needs Java SDK, nope

Comment: @MiPo Where do you see that?  Looks to be cross-platform C without any Java dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the open source project [LMMS](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/). It's a music studio for Linux that includes the ability to use MIDI keyboards with software instruments. If you dig around in [source files](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php?title=Accessing_SVN) with 'midi' in the name, you'll probably find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [Jack](http://jackaudio.org/) source code may help too. It's a sound driver for Posix compatible systems with a lot of possibilities and supports USB and Firewire audio devices.