# C++ MIDI file reading library

Tags: c++, midi

I'm trying to write some software to read a MIDI file into an internal data format and use it to control 3D simulated instruments.
My biggest problem is reading the MIDI data in from a file, and I'd like to avoid writing all the import code.

Does anyone know of a free (preferably Open Source), cross-platform MIDI file reading library?
What features does it have?
Can it import other note-based music formats?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231/c-c-library-for-reading-midi-signals-from-a-usb-midi-device/842632#842632

Answer (score 3):

I once wrote a Midi file read/write library in C. If you want to have a look here it is: http://code.google.com/p/middl/

It's a very basic library that allows you to define a callback function for each MIDI event type, for C++ you might want to encapsulate it into some sort of "Midi reader" class (or just use it as it is :) .

Answer (score 1):

You could try Timidity, an open source midi player written in c. Its quite easy to hack into what you want.